# return variables from functions python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have come across a problem with returning two variables from a function, although I have set the variables to be global. The program I am making is designed to imitate the process of adding a user and login in to that user or changing said user's password.

```
check = False

global uname
global pword

uname = 0
pword = 0

while check == False:


def user(uname, pword):
    set_uname = input("Enter username: ")
    set_pword = input("Enter password: ")
    print("Username and Password set")

    return(set_uname, set_pword)

def login(uname, pword):
    correct = False
    while correct == False:
        enter_uname = input("Enter username: ")
        enter_pword = input("Enter password: ")
        if enter_uname == uname and enter_pword == pword:
            print("Login successful")
        elif enter_uname != uname or enter_pword != pword:
            print("Incorrect username or password")
            correct = False

def cpword(pword):
    done = False
    while done == False:
        check_pword = input("Enter current password: ")
        if check_pword == pword:
            new_pword = input("Enter new password: ")
            if new_pword == pword:
                print("New password cannot be old password")
                done = False
            elif new_pword != pword:
                print("Password successfully changed")
                pword = new_pword
                done = True
                return(pword)
        elif check_pword != pword:
            print("Incorrect password")
            done = False

print("Enter User")
user(uname, pword)

uname = set_uname
pword = set_pword

print("Login = 1")
print("Change Password = 2")

choice = int(input("Enter function: "))

if choice  == 1:
    login(uname, pword)
elif choice == 2:
    cpword(pword)
    pword = pword
```

I keep receiving the error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Users\tay.swain\Documents\Login.py", line 54, in 
>       uname = set_uname
>     NameError: name 'set_uname' is not defined

Once i set the user, when I run the login function this error appears. I am trying to return

> return(set_uname, set_pword)

from the user function. I understand how to return variable from a function as I have done it before, however I cannot get it to work in this code.

Comment: "I have set the variables to be global" <-- Your program does not say that `set_uname` and `set_pword` are global.

Comment: That has worked, I have managed to return variables like that before without setting the variable as global

Comment: Why, exactly, do you expect `set_uname` to be in the global scope? And your `global` directives at the top of you script *are totally redundant*, you are *already in the global scope*. Also, the `user` function returns a pair of values, but you simply discard them when you don't assign the result of the call to anything.... `user(uname, pword)`.

Comment: Returning variables is a pretty simple thing: `def foo(): return 42; bar = foo()`. I'm not sure why you're going through such complicated gymnastics there.

Comment: You need to go back and work through a tutorial about the basics of variable scope, e.g. the difference between local and global variables, as well as how returning values from a function works. You seem to be under the misapprehenesion that *returning* from a function makes the local variables you returned leak into the caller's (in this case, global) scope.

Comment: For example, you seem to think that the variables `pword` and `uname` inside your functions are related to the variables with the same names in the global scope, but those variables are *local to your function* (they have to be, since you made them parameters to your functions!). Even if you return them, that doesn't mean they are related.

Comment: Also, btw, your `login` function will loop forever.

Comment: I have managed to make the user and login function work without continually looping, the only thing now is that the change password function works; however if I try the login function is does not use the new password, it uses the password entered in the user function

Answer (score 4):

You are trying to return two variables from the function, say:

```
def foo():
    a = 1
    b = 2
    return a,b
```

Obviously, if I try to access `a` or `b` from outside the function I will receive the same error that you are seeing, i.e. a `NameError`.

In order to return the values to use outside of the function we can do:

```
c = foo()
print (c)
# (1,2) which is a tuple
```

In order to get whatever you return into two variables, simply use two variables when calling the function:

```
a,b = foo()
print (a,b)
# 1 1
```

Comment: FWIW, those brackets in the `return` statement are superfluous.

Comment: Nitpick, the brackets don't make the tuple, the comma does.

Answer (score 0):

If you do the following, in the output, there would be the "func called" and the "0 1".

```
def func():
    a = 0
    b = 1
    print("func called")
    return a, b

c = func()[0]   # a
d = func()[1]   # b
print(c, d)     # 0, 1
```

So the function is called when you define the global variables.